# JComboBox in Custom table model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have got question about adding `JComboBox`, to Column in Custom table model which extends ObjectTableModel (Table is `OmniJTable`). I work on it 2 days and cannot solve this problem.

One thing I solved is displaying `JComboBox` in Column, but right now I have got problem with selecting anything from it (seems it's not editable, and anything like "setEditable()" not working).

Here is code which one I add `jComboBox` to my `OmniJTable` with ObjectTableModel.

```
class CheckBoxCellRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    JComboBox combo;
    public CheckBoxCellRenderer(JComboBox comboBox) {
        this.combo = new JComboBox();
        for (int i=0; i<comboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
            combo.addItem(comboBox.getItemAt(i));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        combo.setSelectedItem(value);
        return combo;
    }
} 
private void addComboBoxToStatusColumn(JTable table)
{
    final int statusColumnIndex = bazaTelefonowOmniJTable.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Status");

    TableColumn tmpColum = bazaTelefonowOmniJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(statusColumnIndex);
    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    comboBox.setEnabled(true);
    loadRecordStatusFromDictionary(comboBox);


    DefaultCellEditor defaultCellEditor=new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
    tmpColum.setCellEditor(defaultCellEditor);
    tmpColum.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer(comboBox));
    bazaTelefonowOmniJTable.setEditable(true);
    //table.repaint();
}
```

As i said, this one adding jComboBox to Column, but i don't know how to make this one to allow me to choose items in jComboBox.

PS: Sry for my english, it's not my primary language.

Comment: You need to set an editor which is the JComboBox and use Label as the cell renderer. When the user double clicks the cell the combo box is displayed. Drop a message if you need code.

Comment: @KDM Ty for reply, could you paste some code example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is not to add a `CellRenderer`. In that case, the Table renders it as a Label and when clicked the combo box is shown. Here is an example:

```
package snippet;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class JTableTest extends JFrame {

    public JTableTest() {
        super(JTableTest.class.getName());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] { { "1", "One" }, { "2", "Two" } }, new Object[] { "Column One", "Status" });
        addComboBoxToStatusColumn(table);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                new JTableTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addComboBoxToStatusColumn(JTable table) {
        final int statusColumnIndex = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Status");

        TableColumn tmpColum = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(statusColumnIndex);
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        loadRecordStatusFromDictionary(comboBox);

        DefaultCellEditor defaultCellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
        tmpColum.setCellEditor(defaultCellEditor);
    }

    private void loadRecordStatusFromDictionary(JComboBox comboBox) {
        comboBox.addItem("Two");
        comboBox.addItem("Four");
        comboBox.addItem("Six");
    }
}
```

You also need to override the `isCellEditable` method from your model.

```
 model = DaneTableModel(some arg) {
     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if(col == STATUS_COLUMN) return true ;
        return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Code like your's was my first idea to solve this problem, but sadly it's not working on my specific table. 
When i check it with
System.out.println("IsCellEditable = " + bazaTelefonowOmniJTable.isCellEditable(5, statusColumnIndex));

It returns false, is there anything to force those Cells editable ?

Comment: Are you attaching a model to your table? The `TableModel` has a `isCellEditable` that should return true.

Comment: Yup, i have model = DaneTableModel(some arg) (custom model which one extends ObjectTableModel) and bazaTelefonowOmniJTable.setModel(model), before calling my addComboBoxToStatusColumn method. Do you think i should Override some kind of method in DaneTableModel to make those Cells Editable ?

PS: sry for delay i had Internet connection problems :)

Comment: Great answer :) Now it's working fine. Thank you very much :)